# What happens if i leave the Switch in sleep mode for a long time (at least 1 day) and continue playing?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I've not had a switch until Animal Crossing New Horizons, and the last Animal Crossing I even played was Wild World for DS, which didn't have much a real sleep/quick start mode like Switch seems to have.

So my question is, what happens if I leave the game running and just sleep the switch for a period of time. Does the game kick you back out to menu so it can re-calculate everything? does the sun/townsfolk/bugs/etc. just warp around to their 'correct' places. What about time triggered cutscenes (housing upgrades, shop changes, events, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem leaving your switch on sleep. When you come back to the game the next day, it will check your system clock and update the game state accordingly. Cutscenes will start if you have one pending.

Comment: Yeah, tested and confirmed. When Nook does his "daily announcement" is when the game world updates to the correct state.

Comment: Might be worth noting that since "sleep mode" is something the switch just has, games are likely tested for suspend/resume during the certification process.

Comment: Should probably add that it can mess up stuff if you come back without having done an update, if one is available. Sometimes you won't have any popup telling that the update is there.