# Is Leif always on your island the first day of Nature Day?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Today is the start of the [Nature Day event](https://www.inverse.com/gaming/animal-crossing-new-horizons-earth-day-event-start-time-end-date-leif-bush-update) in ACNH so there is a game update.

But I opened my game right after sleep mode and launched it on the older version. Isabelle had no news about Nature Day, nor did Tom Nook. After updating the game and launching it I had new mail regarding the event and Tom Nook spoke about it but nothing more.

I noticed that Leif is present on all of my friend's islands so I'm asking myself if its absence on my island is a bug or a feature.

**Should Leif be on my island on the first day of Nature Day or is it random?**

Comment: Related and might have to be slightly updated : https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/365505/what-happens-if-i-leave-the-switch-in-sleep-mode-for-a-long-time-at-least-1-day

Since I seem to not have the full event, I might not even notice that I'm missing stuff : ask me in a comment if I have [event related stuff] and if I don't I'll edit it to add it to the question.

Comment: I'm facing the same situation as well. I started day on 1.1.4, upgraded to 1.2.0 later.

Comment: Some posts elsewhere on the internet indicate that Leif is absent because you started the game today before upgrading; you thus have to wait until tomorrow to meet Leif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leif is always on your island on the first day of the nature day events that you actually went through the morning announcement of.

So, if you started first day of nature day events on 1.1.4, went through morning announcement, then upgraded to 1.2.0, Leif won't be there, however, she will show up on the next announcement (next day).

[image: Leif on an island on April 24]