# Why didn't Leif arrive on my island for Nature Day?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Yesterday was the first day of Nature day, so I went to log on and discovered it was also the day I got K.K. Slider to perform on my island. Leif didn't show up yesterday, and still hasn’t showed up today.

My game is updated, because Redd is on my island, any suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/368678/143571

Answer (score 2):

For me today was the first day Leif appeared (and the art dealer).

So I guess when KK is in town, any other random appearance in the square is cancelled, and it leaves the space for KK.

So I guess the game skipped your first 'Leif day' and he will appear the next time he would be scheduled to. (I don't know if he is on a schedule or like other 'square vendors' he has a chance to appear every day.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug/oversight by Nintendo. Just wait for Leif to come back to your island later. You could also always time-skip back to the day leif was supposed to be there and see if that works.